# No "Denoising Data" checkmark in View Layer Properties

Tags: compositing-nodes

A few days ago, I posted a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com) asking why the Render Layers node didn't have sockets for denoising, and the answer was that I did not have "Denoising Data" checked in **View Layer Properties > Passes**.  However, this time, that checkmark is not there.  How do I make it appear?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Denoising data is for the cycles render engine, not for eevee.

[image]